# validating user input using flask_wtf and sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

Noob question. I am building a login/registration pages, on the registration page, I am using flask_wtf to verify certain things like length of password, email format and whether the two password a user supplies match. Here is the flask_wtf code I am using to do that.

```
# import statements omitted for brevity 
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username',
                           validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    email = StringField('Email',validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password',
             validators=[DataRequired(),Length(min=4, max=20), EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')
```

After checking the input, I am using sqlalchemy to check if the username and email already exists in my DB. The problem I am facing right now is I cant get flask_wtf to verify the form. I can type whatever I want and it will be converted to a sql query. Here are my two flask routes that handle registration and user input validation.

```
@app.route('/register',methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():

     form = RegistrationForm()

     if form.validate_on_submit():

         return redirect(url_for('check_user_input'))

     return render_template('register.html',form=form)

@app.route('/status',methods=['POST'])
def check_user_input():

    name = request.form.get("username")

    email = request.form.get("email")

    password = request.form.get("password")

    if db.execute("SELECT * FROM DB WHERE username= :username",{"username":name}).rowcount==1:

        return render_template("404.html", message="Sorry username already exists")

    elif db.execute("SELECT * FROM DB WHERE email= :email", 
         {"email":email}).rowcount==1:

         return render_template("404.html", message="Sorry email already exists")

    else:
        db.execute("INSERT INTO DB (username,email,password) VALUES 
        (:username,:email,:password)",

        {"username":name, "email":email,"password":password})

        db.commit()

        return render_template("success.html")
```

How can I get flask_wtf form to do its verification first and then hand the input to `check_user_input()` function?

My register.html contains the following line.

```
<form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="{{url_for('check_user_input')}}">
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A way is to add a custom validation to the form :

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username',
                           validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    email = StringField('Email',validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password',
             validators=[DataRequired(),Length(min=4, max=20), EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')

    def validate(self):
        rv = FlaskForm.validate(self)
        if not rv:
            return False

        if db.execute("SELECT * FROM DB WHERE username= :username",{"username":self.username.data}).rowcount>0:
            self.username.errors.append('Sorry username already exists')
            return False
        if db.execute("SELECT * FROM DB WHERE email= :email", {"email":self.email.data}).rowcount>0:
            self.email.errors.append('Sorry email already exists')
            return False
        return True
```